# adding static table of content to html

Tags: javascript, html, tags

```
<body>
    <div id="tag1"></div>
    <div id="tag2" class="tag2"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    <iframe src="help.html" width="100%" height="300">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
     </iframe>
</body>
```

I have code like above in a html file. It displays the content as -

```
=====          ====
tag1           tag2
=====          ====
--------------------
  help.html 

  Intro
    some intro.
  basics 
    some basic info.
   and more contents
--------------------
```

Now I would like add "table of content" to right side of help.html.so that user can easily access appropriate location within help.html .For example

```
=====          ====
tag1           tag2
=====          ====
--------------------
help.html      Intro <----|
               basics <---| new thing I would like to add
               topic3 <---|
  Intro
    some intro
  basics 
    some basic info.
   and more contents
--------------------
```

I tried to add iframe and few thing with help from google..but I'm not sure how to get it 
right. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done easily with CSS using the `position: fixed` property:

```
div.table-of-contents {
    position: fixed;

    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

See my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yDBPZ/3/